# Customize devise confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable

> Welcome xxx@xxxxx.com! You can confirm your account email through the
>   link below: enter code hereConfirm my account

I want to edit this message to become like this

> My project_name
>   Hello xxxxx 
>   click here to confirm you email

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply  generate the devise views

> rails g devise:views

then you get access to the default mailing configurations in

> your_app/app/views/devise/mailer

- confirmation_instructions.html.erb
- reset_password_instructions.html.haml
- unlock_instructions.html.haml

Comment: This is still right with rails 4.2 / Devise 3.5
Note that if you have several devise models, the mail directory will be created in each devise model view directory: `your_app/app/views/user/mailer` and `your_app/app/views/admin/mailer` for example...

Answer (score 4):

Check the `devise.en.yml` to find the devise translations. You can pass the `project_name` to the translation; for example:

`t('welcome', :project_name => project.name)`

And in the yml file:

`welcome_message: 'My %{project_name} Hello xxxxx click here to confirm you email'`

Comment: You mean under 
 mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: 'Cheeve.it Confirmation instructions'
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: 'Reset password instructions'
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: 'Unlock Instructions'

Answer (score 3):

I believe you wanted to customize `confirmation_instructions.html.erb` file from `app\view\resource\mailer` when usually resource is *users* or *admin*

First of all, check if you set `config.scoped_views = true` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` Thanks to this, setup devise is looking for templates in your resource's view folder instead of default one in `app\views\devise\mailer`

Using `login`, `username` etc. is possible in following way `<%= @resource.login %>`

After all, make sure to restart server. For reference, check similar issue [Ruby/Rails: How do you customize the mailer templates of Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276233/ruby-rails-how-do-you-customize-the-mailer-templates-of-devise)